# What are the correct Google Compute Engine scopes for Stackdriver Trace and Cloud PubSub?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm trying to setup a node pool/cluster that includes the scopes for trace and pubsub, but the docs seems to leave both scopes out of the list.

https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/instances/create

Answer (score 2):

The documentation of the APIs should always mention the required OAuth scopes. Here's what I've found:

For Stackdriver Trace, the required OAuth scope is `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/trace.append`, documented e.g. in the [Stackdriver Trace API documentation for patchTraces](https://cloud.google.com/trace/docs/reference/v1/rest/v1/projects/patchTraces#authorization).

For Cloud Pub/Sub, the required OAuth scope is `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/pubsub`, documented e.g. in the [Cloud Pub/Sub API documentation for publish](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.topics/publish#authorization).